# Requesting specific file from a server via socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer

I found some code that transfers files between a client and a server. But the file location and port numbers are hard coded. I was wondering if there is a way in which a client can specify what file s/he needs from the server - so that when the server receives the request, it can send that particular file to the client. Thank you.

---

Edit [1]: Code snippet and context description:

I am adding the code I have so far, based on the feedbacks and comments. Hopefully, this answers some questions in the comment section.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * Original coder adapted from:
 * http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0542.html
 *
 * Best intentions:
 * This program runs both as server and client.
 * 
 * The client asks for a specific file from _
 * the server x number of times in a loop.
 * 
 * Server simply serves the file requested.
 */

public class FileServer extends Thread {

    public static void server() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(13267);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Waiting...");

            Socket sock = servsock.accept();
            System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);

            //Retrieve filename to serve
            InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String fileName = bfr.readLine();
            bfr.close();

            System.out.println("Server side got the file name:" + fileName);

            //Sendfile
            File myFile = new File(fileName);
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("Sending...");
            os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            os.flush();
            sock.close();
        }
    }

    public static void client(int index) throws IOException {
        int filesize = 6022386; // filesize temporary hardcoded

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int bytesRead;
        int current = 0;
        //Localhost for testing
        Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 13267);

        System.out.println("Connecting...");

        //Ask for specific file: source1
        String fileName = "source1";
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);
        pw.println(fileName);


        //Receive file
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[filesize];
        InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("source1-copy" + index);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        current = bytesRead;

        // thanks to A. Cádiz for the bug fix
        do {
            bytesRead =
                    is.read(mybytearray, 
                            current, (mybytearray.length - current));
            if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                current += bytesRead;
            }
        } while (bytesRead > -1);

        bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
        bos.flush();

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end - start);
        os.flush();

        bos.close();
        sock.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileServer fs = new FileServer();
        fs.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(
                   FileServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            client(i);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            server();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(
                   FileServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it is getting stuck at "Connecting ..." line. Here is the output:

> Waiting...
>   Accepted connection : Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=44939,localport=13267]
>   Connecting...

Comment: What protocol are you talking about?  HTTP?  FTP?

Comment: Just use one of the standardized file copy protocols like scp, http or (shudder) ftp.

Comment: You certainly request an specific file when you make an HTTP request (I guess this is what you're talking about). What does the server does about this request and its parameters, is a choice in your configuration.

Comment: If the code you found is hardcoded to use certain file locations and ports, then it sounds like the solution is to simply make it so this is a parameter in the request. In other words... remove the hard-coding.

Comment: Maybe BackOrifice does what you want.

Comment: @Kirk Client is communicating directly with the Server via TCP I believe.

Comment: @fvu I guess my ultimate goal and these routes differ somewhat. I am planning to write a basic peer code - so that I can implement a simple p2p setup with an index server once I overcome these obstacles. So, in the mean time I keep the protocol direct and simple I guess.

Comment: @matt Please see the edits. I have tried to use 'parameters'.

Comment: @Roland I will check BackOrifice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@moejoe I think you're over thinking this.

If you have it in place to send a file already, then the first thing to do is abstract that functionality out so you can run it as a method and supply a pathname/filename.

Then you can use the socket (which is two way) to send a message from the client to the server asking for what file you want. Beyond that, it's a matter of how to get the file you want from the UI. You may need to have the server supply a method of "list available files", i.e. ls functionality.

This is all fairly trivial to implement.

Comment: @glowcoder I think you are right. I did modify my code based on your suggestion, but I have a new problem now. Please see my edits. Thank you.

Comment: @moejoe Personally, I wouldn't send the bytes across from the client to the server. I would just send a message in a String - it's easier to parse and work with. Wrap your OutputStream in a PrintWriter, and use a `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream())`. Then in the client you can do `pw.println(filename);` and in your server go `String filename = br.readLine();`

Comment: @glowcoder I made the changes, but the issue still persists. The code gets stuck at "Connecting ..." as I mentioned in my edit. I guess this is an issue with the way I am creating the thread?

Comment: @glowcoder The filename is not being read at the server side - I just checked - I doubt if the client is even being able to send the file name across.

Comment: According to the code in your post right now... Your server is using `readLine()` but your client isn't passing a line. It's never actually ENDING the line. As far as the server is concerned, it's still reading a partially completed line. If you change the client side (only) to use a PrintWriter and use `println(filename)` it should show up on the Server.

Comment: @glowcoder - I figured that and changed the code (edit posted) but still the same issue.

Comment: I will take some ideas from here and will let you know if this works - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html